# How to use Vectors in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, svg

I'm looking for solution of problem that I get image from my server and that image will be only be one(not for compatible all devices) and that image will also use in android device too so as you know android support SVG but iOS isn't (that 1 image should be use on all iOS devices even on iPad too). I look into this [Tutorial](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/) and this use from PDF and also use local pdf.

So what will be approach from iOS end or server end to download 1 image (with one size) and will be show on all devices.

Looking for suggestions and help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement PocketSVG (https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG) to do that.

There is one downfall though: it only supports SVG features that can be drawn using `CGPaths` or `UIPaths`.